# MySQL Query to Group Messages as Conversation

Tags: mysql, message, grouping

I need to show messages as conversation in my user's inbox. Grouped by sender and displaying the last message (either last message received from the sender or my latest reply to that sender).

So far my current MySQL query only shows all received messages without any grouping.

Here's my database structure:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                  users_messages                                   |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| message_ID | from_id | to_id | date | subject | body | unread | delete1 | delete2 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

+---------------------+
|        users        |
+---------------------+
| id | username | ... 
+----+----------+-----+
```

Here is my current query:

```
$result = $DB->query("SELECT p.*, p.sender as sender, m.*
FROM  " . DB_PREFIX . "messages p
LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "members m ON p.sender=m.member_id
WHERE p.receiver='" . $SESSION->conf['member_id'] . "' AND delete2=0
ORDER BY p.senddate DESC
LIMIT " . (($page - 1) * $PREFS->conf['per_page']) . ", " . $PREFS->conf['per_page']);
```

Comment: There is no "conversation" to group by in your structure. Do you mean a unique combination of `from_id` and `to_id`? How would you like the messages to come from the DB?

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply. I'm currently using the traditional style in which, messages are displayed in INBOX and SENT items, each messages as separate entries. I do not want that anymore. I need to show them all in the INBOX. Each messages are grouped by the sender, which also includes my replies to that sender, thus showing my conversation with that sender.

if you do not get what I mean. check facebook. :)

Comment: Facebook is not a database.

Comment: are you a troll or something? of course i know facebook is not a database. even newbies knows that. lol

Comment: Facebook uses PHP and Web Servers to deliver HTML that shows the conversations. You are asking about MySQL here - you will never ever get HTML out of MySQL. Well, I guess it's not absolutely impossible, but... ;)

Comment: I never said i am using HTML. Of course I am using PHP. :)

Answer (score 3):

Kind of messy - but should work for you:

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    user_messages 
WHERE 
    message_ID IN ( 
    SELECT 
        MAX(message_ID) 
    FROM 
        (SELECT 
            IF(m.from_id = <THE USER ID>, m.to_id, m.from_id) as other_user_id, 
            m.message_id 
        FROM 
            users_messages m 
        WHERE 
            m.from_id = <THE USER ID> OR m.to_id = <THE USER ID>) me 
    GROUP BY 
        other_user_id 
    ) 
ORDER BY 
    message_id DESC
```

Comment: hi this is my current query:
`$result = $DB->query("SELECT p.*, p.sender as sender, m.*
FROM  " . DB_PREFIX . "messages p
LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "members m ON p.sender=m.member_id
WHERE p.receiver='" . $SESSION->conf['member_id'] . "' AND delete2=0
ORDER BY p.senddate DESC
LIMIT " . (($page - 1) * $PREFS->conf['per_page']) . ", " . $PREFS->conf['per_page']);`

Comment: OK? have you tried something along the lines of what I have suggested. That should give you the most recent message in each conversation of that user.

Comment: what should i put in this <THE USER ID>?